# Undefined variable: content

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables, model-view-controller, undefined

My error:Message: Undefined variable: content
the "content"variable used in my view is apparently not defined. however, when i do var_dump($result); to test the content.. i get:

> array(1) { [0]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> string(3) "148" ["description"]=>
>   string(9) "33" ["date"]=> string(10) "2015-05-30" ["status"]=>
>   string(1) "1" ["Title"]=> string(2) "33" ["notes"]=> string(9) "33"
>   ["time"]=> string(8) "07:28:36" } }

MY CONTROLLER:

```
public function edit_news_form() {

   $this->load->view('edit_news_form');

    $this->load->model('users_model');
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $result=$this->users_model->get_id($id);
    $data['content']=$result;

   }


   public function edit(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('users_model');
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $result=$this->users_model->get_id($id);
    $data['content']=$result;

    $this->db->trans_start();       

    $title = $this->input->post('title');
    $notes = $this->input->post('notes');
    $description = $this->input->post('description');
    $date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('date')));
    $status = 1;
    $time = date('h:i:s',strtotime($this->input->post('time')));

    $data = array(
            'Title' => $title,
            'description' => $description,
            'date'=>$date,
            'time'=>$time,
            'status' => $status,
            'notes' => $notes,
            );
    $this->users_model->update($id,$data);
    $this->db->trans_complete();

   }

}
```

MY MODEL:

```
 function get_id($id){
        $this->db->where('id',$id);     
        $query = $this->db->get('news');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

function update($id,$data){
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('news',$data);
    }
```

MY VIEW:

```
     <label>

         <?php echo form_open('resetPasswordController/edit/'.$this->uri->segment(3))?>
        <textarea name="description" rel="815"><?php echo $content[0]['description'];?></textarea>
    </div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the $data variable in the view method. Take a look at this:

```
public function edit_news_form()
{
    $this->load->model('users_model');
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $result=$this->users_model->get_id($id);
    $data['content']=$result;

    $this->load->view('edit_news_form', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem: even if my form fields meet the rules the codeigniter form validation still returns false (error).

example:

```
   public function edit(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'title', 'required|xss_clean|trim|is_unique[news.Title]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'description', 'required|xss_clean|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('notes', 'notes', 'required|xss_clean|trim');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $data['error'] =  '';
        $data['page_title']="Edit News";
        echo "error";

    }
    else {
    ..........
```

if i leave the fields empty it will tell me to enter something because they cant be left empty. if i type something then it returns error once i submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
```

means that the form has no errors

Comment: yes i know. but it never runs this as true. it always echoes false. even if the set_rules are met it still echoes "error"

Comment: my problem was that i didn't pass $data when loading the view file. thanks anyways :D